# Whats the logic behind NSTimer when applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

i have a implemented `NSTimer` with `timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(methodName) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];` in `UIViewController`.

It is working fine without any issue. But if when i click iphone home button `applicationDidEnterBackground` will be call. I minimize the application for `10 second` than i open app again. So `methodName` will be called after `10 second` and its working. i dont have any issue with this. I just want to know that when app gone in `backgroud`mode `timer` is running on backgroud ???

i think it timer is working in backgroud so it call after `10 second` otherwise it called after `20 second`.

What `timer` will do when app is go in `backgroud mode` ?? It preserve the last time ?

`NSTimer` will consume the memory in `backgroud` ??

Comment: timer will paused when app enters background and will start from the paused state  when app enters foreground

Comment: it won't run in background you have to manage in your app when your app goes in background and when it comes in foreground.

Comment: check this :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613487/timer-how-to-remain-timer-active-in-background

Comment: @AmanAggarwal so it will automatically Paused and start(with last time) when app is in background to forground ?

Comment: No, it won't. The timer does keep running. It doesn't resume from where you shut it down. If you click the home button right after it fires, then wait 15 seconds and restart the app, it will fire in approx. 5 seconds, not almost 20. Test it yourself, it's easy enough to do.

Comment: @rdelmar yes i have test this. so according to you  timer is running in backgroud ? not gone to Pause state and resume state ?