# Call a method with delay of 15 sec irrespective of app state

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I need to call a method in every 15 seconds irrespective of any fact, whether it is on any view controller in `foreground`, whether it is in `background` or it is `killed`, I need to call it at all times.

I know I can do the delay task using `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 15.0 target: self
                               selector: @selector(callAfterFifteenSeconds:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

But, I wanted to know where to implement it so that it could fulfil my condition. I guess I can use it in `App Delegate` but I need a guidance for this to implement it correctly.

Comment: How can you expect your code to call a method if the app is killed?

Comment: I also dont know that but thats the requirement I wanted to fulfill. Thats what I asked for help on SO

Comment: when the app is killed, it won't do anything, so timer/ anything else won't work in this case.

Comment: i am sorry, but the person who has provided these requirements should again review it at-least once as far as doing something on the killed app is concerned

Comment: You need to use background process to do such task when app get killed...

Comment: @FahimParkar Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Calling it in App Delegate class is right place but it will not work for following cases.

- It will not work if your app is killed from back ground.
- It will not in background mode continuously. OS will stop that process after certain period of time.

Answer (score 1):

-If the app is killed, you cannot do anything.

-When the app is in background, the OS may kill that process after certain time interval (I believe it is 15 seconds).

Though you can register for location changes, while the app is in background. In that case, your app will continue to receive location updates (such as for google maps).

```
-(void)callAfterFifteenSeconds {

    //1.) do your work


    //2.) If required, you can also choose to skip the next scheduling.
    BOOL shouldSchedule = YES;

    if (shouldSchedule) {
        //3.)
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(15 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //
            [self callAfterFifteenSeconds];

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4.0f];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                    ^{
               //write you code if you want fire any method after 4 sec//          

                    }
                    );
```

Comment: Could you please explain me your answer?

Comment: Please explain the benefit of using this NSThread & the block.

Comment: if you want to to call any method after some time then this method are use in implement to call those method after some time on main queue...

Comment: But that I can achieve using `NSTimer` too